# Hybridauth Social Login Failure

Tags: php, hybridauth

I'm following this example of social login integration using Hybridauth with Google and Twitter:

[Hybridauth Example](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Integrating_HybridAuth_Social_Login.html)

When I try to sign up (first time), `HTTP Error 500` appears (or blank page when I'm using Firefox). However, the new user is created in de database.

Then, I try to log in again with the same user, and it shows this error:

```
Error: Duplicate entry 'xxxxx@gmail.com' for key 'email'
```

(I'm using echo when it catches an exception in `login.php`)

When I check `error_log` the following error appears:

```
[01-Nov-2016 15:34:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Database error:  in /***/conect.php on line 19
[01-Nov-2016 15:34:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /***/conect.php on line 18
```

This is working the same for Google and Twitter

I can't figure out what's going wrong